# Cast object to int[]

Tags: c#, object, arraylist

I have a array (with type of Object) which I'm extracting from a System.Collections.ArrayList. And I'm now trying to cast this object to a int[] so i can use it to compare it with another int[].

Note: I'm currently using .Net Framework 7.0.0

```
var query = (from el in l
                     where el.ID_Seal_From != "" && el.ID_Seal_From != null
                     select new
                     {
                         conn = el.Conn_from,
                         seal = el.ID_Seal_From
                     }).ToList();


        var query2 = (from el in l
                      where el.ID_Seal_To != "" && el.ID_Seal_To != null
                      select new
                      {
                          conn = el.Conn_to,
                          seal = el.ID_Seal_To
                      }).ToList();

        var res = query.Concat(query2).ToList();
        
        
        ArrayList arrLi = new();
        List<int> indexOfEqualElements = new();
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < res.Count; j++)
            {
                if (res[i].seal.CompareTo(res[j].seal) == 0)
                {
                    indexOfEqualElements.Add(j);
                }
            }

            if (Contains(arrLi, indexOfEqualElements.ToArray()) == -1) //to avoid multiple entries
            {
                arrLi.Add(indexOfEqualElements.ToArray());
            }
            indexOfEqualElements.Clear();
        }
```

In the "contains" call I'm trying to compare the Elements. For this case i need to avoid, that two equal arrays get added to the list. Because afterwards i need this distinct dataset to continue

Comment: You really shouldn't be using a `ArrayList` in the first place, if you can possibly help it. They've been effectively obsolete since 2005.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can't cast an `object[]` as type `int[]` because it's not that type. If you want an `int[]` then create an `int[]` in the first place. Show us the code that you should have posted to begin with and we'll show you what to change and how.

Comment: You probably can't do that. But maybe you can cast it to an ArrayList and then convert that list into an int[]?

Comment: Taking a step back... Why are you boxing your types into `Object` in the first place?  Why not use an `int[]` or a `List<int>`?

Comment: There's no such thing as .NET Framework 7. The last version of .NET Framework was 4.8. After .NET 3.1 came .NET 5, which was based on .NET Core but basically merged .NET Framework into it. .NET 6 followed and .NET 7 is in preview. It's just .NET now.

Comment: Also, how exactly do you want to compare? You can probably compare the `ArrayList` directly, if you do it properly. That said, if you were doing it properly, you'd probably be using a `List<int>` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for not trying to understand all the code above, but you simply can cast all the values of an ArrayList to an IEnumerable like this:

```
var arrayList = new ArrayList(2)
{
    1,
    2
};

var integerEnumerable = arrayList
    .Cast<int>();
```

Feel free to add an .ToArray(), if you like an int[] instead.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is deprecated. If you wanted a list you should use `List<int>`. In this instance, it seems you actually need something like a `HashSet<int>`.

But to just get distinct elements you can simply use `DistinctBy`.

```cs
var query = (
    from el in l
    where el.ID_Seal_From != "" && el.ID_Seal_From != null
    select new
    {
        conn = el.Conn_from,
        seal = el.ID_Seal_From
    });

var query2 = (
    from el in l
    where el.ID_Seal_To != "" && el.ID_Seal_To != null
    select new
    {
        conn = el.Conn_to,
        seal = el.ID_Seal_To
    });

var res = query.Concat(query2).DistinctBy(el => el.seal);
```